# Methods not being executed

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5

I have a iPad app, using Storyboards, XCode 4.5 and iOS6.  In one of the "scenes" I have a UITableView in the upper left quadrant, some UITextFields in the right quadrant and a UITableView in the bottom half.  There are no controllers for the two (2) UITableViews.  The problem is that numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView are never called.

Here is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
#import "ClientInfo.h"

@interface ClientViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>   {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *clientView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *clientImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *previousAppointments;


@end
```

Here is is the .m file

```
#import "ClientViewController.h"

@interface ClientViewController ()  {

}

@end

@implementation ClientViewController

//@synthesize clientPicture;

//-----------------------------------------------
- (void)viewDidLoad  {
#define kBorderWidth 2.0
#define kCornerRadius 8.0

    [super viewDidLoad];


    //  draw a border around UIImageView
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(405, 50, 106, 106);  //  x, y, width, height
    [borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];

    [borderLayer setCornerRadius:kCornerRadius];
    [borderLayer setBorderWidth:kBorderWidth];
    [borderLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [self.clientView.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];


}


//------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == _clientView)  {
            // Return number of rows for first table view...
        }
    else if(tableView == _previousAppointments) {
            // Return number of rows for second table view...
        }
        return 0;
}


//---------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  {

    return 1;  //  returns number of sections

}

//-------------------------------------------------

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning  {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

UPDATE:  I connected the UITableViews to the datasource and delegates using CTRL + drag/drop against the Connections Inspector.  I am now getting this error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb86a4f0'

What am I doing wrong, or not doing correctly?

Comment: you've declared _clientView as a UIView, but you're using it like a UITableView.

Comment: i will say recheck your IBOutlets connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked whether the View Controller is the Table Views datasource?

Comment: I was connecting to the UIView and not the UIViewController... took a while for me to figure it out, but with some help from Abizern, I did.